# Not installed or installed?

Tags: perl, cpan

I have a problem in installing modules CPAN on my pc.
I wanted to install a module from CPAN and the problem is ... If i do that command :
`perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::DT'`
The answer is : 
`XML::DT is up to date (0.63).`
But when i try to run my program with the module XML::DT, it tells me that i don't have installed !
So... What options do i have to solve this?

Error given to me is :

```
Can't locate XML/DT.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.16 
/Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/Network/Library/Perl/5.16 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 
/System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/System/Library/Perl/5.16 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level 
/System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16 .) at ./EX.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./EX.pl line 2.
```

Comment: Can't resist: "Installed or not installed, that is a question"... ShakesPERL's Hamlet. ;) :)

Comment: How are you running the script?  Is it running, for example, from within Padre or some other IDE?  Or are you running it from the command line? And do you know *where* the module has been installed to?  (Because it probably hasn't been installed to one of the paths listed in @INC)

Comment: To see where the module is installed, do `perl -MXML::DT -e 'print $INC{"XML/DT.pm"}, "\n"'`. My guess is you have more than one perl installation.

Comment: Well, i did it working using the command `use lib ...` but i think it mustn't do that ... :/

Comment: I'm running the script via `iTerm` (command line)

Comment: @friedo  i did what you told me , and it gave me only one response.

Comment: your @INC looks like you have 2 5.16 dirs, one just 5.16 and one with space at the end. So, it's very likely you have 2 installations (not for the package of your concern but overall) If you clean up '5.16 ', it may help

Comment: How am i supposed to do that ? :/

Comment: can you post the output of this command `instmodsh`

Comment: `Available commands are:
   l            - List all installed modules
   m <module>   - Select a module
   q            - Quit the program
cmd?`